# Bypass login page in .NET Code

Tags: .net, api, rss

I am writing a .NET API which downloads xml data from an RSS Feed.

The RSS Feed is a private feed which uses login creds which I have and I can use them to access the feed. The moment I run the API, it comes back with that login page code. Is there any way I can bypass that login page?

Code to get the content

```
    string feedURL = "RSS feed url here";
var webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.Headers.Add("user-agent",
    "Mozilla/4.0 (Compatible; Windows NT 5.1; MSIE 6.0) " +
    "(compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; " +
    ".NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)");//"Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Job Feed Importer;)");

var content = webClient.OpenRead(feedURL);
var contentReader = new StreamReader(content);
var rssFeedAsString = contentReader.ReadToEnd();
rssFeedAsString = rssFeedAsString.Trim();
Console.WriteLine(rssFeedAsString);
```

And Response of above code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 8]>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="ie8" lang="en-US">
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !(IE 8) ]><!-->
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en-US">
<!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

<form name="loginform" id="loginform" action="https://RSSfeed_hostname_here/authorize/" method="post">
<p>
<label for="user_login">Username<br />
<input type="text" name="log" id="user_login" class="input" value="" size="20" /></label>
</p>
<p>
<label for="user_pass">Password<br />
<input type="password" name="pwd" id="user_pass" class="input" value="" size="20" /></label>
</p>
<p class="forgetmenot"><label for="rememberme"><input name="rememberme" type="checkbox" id="rememberme" value="forever"  /> Remember Me</la
bel></p>
<p class="submit">
<input type="submit" name="wp-submit" id="wp-submit" class="button button-primary button-large" value="Log In" />
<input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="https://RSSfeed_hostname_here/feed/?fsk=some_random_chars_here&amp;username=login_username_here&amp;password=login_password_here" />
<input type="hidden" name="testcookie" value="1" />
</p>
</form>
<p id="nav">
<a href="" title=""></a>
</p>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</body>
</html>

);
```

I am not a pro coder so please spare me if the code is not optimized or anything.

Comment: You have the credentials for the RSS feed. Can you contact the owner of the RSS for get a workaround?.

Comment: I honestly don't know how bypass login, that would be very difficult without more info, Can you explain why you can't contact with owner of the RSS? My suggestions are: 1) un the URL, pass as QueryStrings the credentials `this could fail since we don't know the keys of the QueryStrings` 2) log in first `as usual` and try execute your code again,